# Website menu wrong colour in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: wordpress, menu, colors, internet-explorer-9

I have a Wordpress site, it looks great in Chrome.  But when I look at it in IE9, the hover drop down menu is a horrible blue colour.  Not what it should be.  Any ideas why it looks different?

There should also be an image of a mobile on the right hand side of the homepage, but it isnt there in IE9.

My website:
http://goo.gl/YpcKBx

Answer (score 0):

You're you using CSS gradients.

They're not supported in IE9 or earlier, so the browser will fall back to whatever else has been defined as an alternative background-colour. I guess you've got that blue somewhere in your stylesheets.

Solutions:

1. Use an alternative syntax that IE9 does support such as an SVG background image for your gradient.
2. Use a polyfill script like CSS3Pie which can help old IE versions support features like CSS gradients.
3. Accept that old IE versions don't support this feature, and provide a plain-colour fall-back background colour that is close enough to your intended gradient that it looks okay.

Comment: Great, thanks for that.  It isnt important for me to have a gradient background, so I will attempt to change it to a flat colour when I get home.  Thanks for the fast reply and will keep you informed.